# Improved AFK command for discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have recently viewed a AFK command from a different thread. Here is the code:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 // checks if the message author is afk
 if (db.has(message.author.id + '.afk')) {
  message.channel.send(`Welcome back ${message.author} I removed your AFK.`);
  db.delete(message.author.id + '.afk');
  db.delete(message.author.id + '.messageafk');
 }
 if (message.content.startsWith('+afk')) {
  message.channel.send(
   'Aight, I have set your AFK. I will send a message to the users who mention you..'
  );
  // then here you use the database :
  db.set(message.author.id + '.afk', 'true');
  db.set(
   message.author.id + '.messageafk',
   message.content.split(' ').slice(2)
  );
 }
 if (message.content.includes('+afk off')) {
  db.delete(message.author.id + '.afk');
  db.delete(message.author.id + '.messageafk');
 }
});
```

When user pinged:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 // If one of the mentions is the user
 message.mentions.users.forEach((user) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return false;

  if (
   message.content.includes('@here') ||
   message.content.includes('@everyone')
  )
   return false;
  if (db.has(user.id + '.afk'))
   message.channel.send(
    `${message.author}, the user you mentioned is currently AFK.. Leave a message if urgent by DMing him`
   );
 });
});
```

I want to add an AFK reason to be shown instead of that message when the user is mentioned

Expected output:

```
User: +afk <reason>
BOT: Aight, I have set your AFK. I will send a message to the users who mention you..
User2: @User
BOT: @User2, the user you mentioned is currently AFK: <reason>
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly? To me it's unclear, can you please edit your question so you point out the problem?

Comment: it looks like you need something more than `.has` is there a `.get` or `.fetch` to really get the data?  Generally the .has will tell you T/F if the artifact exists.  If it does, you will need to request it.

Answer (score 2):

The first and maybe the easiest way of getting this info: using `Array.prototype.splice()`

```js
const reason = [...message.content].splice(5).join('')
```

```js
const message = '+afk doing homework';
const reason = [...message].splice(5).join('');
console.log(reason);
```

---

Second method: use `String.prototype.split()`:

```js
const reason = message.content.split(/ +/).splice(1).join(' ');
```

```js
const message = '+afk doing homework';
const reason = message.split(/ +/).splice(1).join(' ');
console.log(reason);
```

---

Lastly, also using `String.prototype.split()`:

```js
const reason = message.content.split('+afk ')[1]
```

```js
const message = '+afk doing homework';
const reason = message.split('+afk ')[1];
console.log(reason);
```

---

Once you have the reason, you can add it to the database, and fetch it whenever

Answer (score 0):

here :

```js
    if (message.content.startsWith('+afk')) {
      message.channel.send('Aight, I have set your AFK. I will send a message to the users who mention you..')
// then here you use the database :
db.set(message.author.id + '.afk','true')
db.set(message.author.id + '.messageafk', message.content.split(' ').slice(2))
    }
    if (message.content.includes('+afk off')) {
db.delete(message.author.id + '.afk')
db.delete(message.author.id + '.messageafk')
    }
});
```

there is this line :

```js
db.set(message.author.id + '.messageafk', 'THE MESSAGE TO BE SENT')
```

There you will set the ask reason,and you will display it when the user is mentionned

```js
client.on('message', message =>{
if(message.author.bot) return;
if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
// if the message author was afk
if(db.get('afkusers').includes(message.author.id){
message.channel.send('Oh you're back ! Removed your afk')
db.delete('afkusers[afkusers.indexoF(message.author.id)]')
}
// if one of the mentions is a afk user
// Oh and you need to use 'if(user.bot) return;' because a bot can't use your commands ^^'
// if there is afk users (don't delete it's important so we are such that the variable will work and we can use normal js to manipulate the variable like .includes())
if(db.has('afkusers')){
// If one of the mentions is afk
if(message.mentions.users.find(u => db.get('afkusers').includes(u.id)) message.channel.send(`${message.author}, the user you mentioned is currently AFK.. Leave a message if urgent by DMing him`)

}
})
```

Comment: As you have written the code.. I believe you can answer this question. 
Is it possible to make the bot send what the user wants. Such as if i i'm AFK cuz i got to go sleep so when i type `+afk Sleeping` whenever the user is pinged or mentioned the bot sends. `User is AFK : Sleeping`. So +afk 'USER REASON' . Can you help me do that. Meaning the user desired reason. How can I make the bot do that. This is the best I could explain..

Comment: yea- in the place where i set the reason variable to the databas : `db.set(message.author.id + '.messageafk', 'THE MESSAGE TO BE SENT')` you replace THE_MESSAGE.. by what you want the user. I think what you want is : `message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')` this will split the message by the white space, delete the command, then join it again, this way you will have the arguments of the user as the message UvU

Comment: Oh thank you. Also if you don't mind i believe you should edit your answer to a single final code. Helping others understand the code and use it easily. That's just a suggestion btw..